# How would I create lists for metric and imperial?

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to put the data input into the program and append it to the lists, but I'm not sure how. My original plan was to create "while" loops and if the length in imperial was 0, then metric would be used to calculate bmi. If not, imperial would be used. I'm just having some trouble figuring out how to do that and how to append the data to their respective lists. It's really important to use lists for that data in this assignment, I just can't figure it out. Thank you!!!

```
def inputM():
  print("Enter weight in kg")
  weightm = float(input())
  print("Enter height in meters")
  heightm = float(input())
  return weightm, heightm
def inputI():
  print("Enter weight in pounds")
  weighti = float(input())
  print("Enter height in inches")
  heighti = float(input())
  return weighti, heighti

def healthindex (preference, bmi):
  if preference == "b": 
    print("BMI " + str(round(bmi,2)))
  elif preference == "h":
    index = 0
    print("your BMI is " + str(round(bmi,2)))
    while index < len(BMIList):
      if bmi < BMIValues[index]:
        print ("And, you are " + BMIList[index])
        return
      index = index + 1
    print("You are Obese")
  else:
    print("Invalid choice")
  return

BMIList = ["severly underweight", "underweight", "healthy", "overweight", "obese"]
BMIValues = [15.99, 18.49, 24.99, 29.99, 500]
print("Welcome to BMI Calculator!")
print("Enter I for Imperial or M for Metric")
request = input().upper()

if request == "M":
  weightm, heightm = inputM()
  bmi = weightm/(heightm**2)
elif request == "I":
  weighti, heighti = inputI()
  bmi = (703*weighti)/(heighti**2)  
else:
  print("Invalid input")

print("Enter b to only see your bmi or enter h if you would like to see your bmi and your corresponding health index!")

preference = input()
healthindex (preference, bmi)
```

Comment: To clarify terminology: `if` is not a "loop" because it doesn't repeat.

Comment: Now as for your qeustion, what is the goal of this code. What is it supposed to do? Describe this in terms so that anyone can understand, even if they don't know python. Then describe what your code does when you run it and how the result differs from what you expect.

Comment: The goal of this code is to calculate bmi. I differentiate between imperial and metric with request statements, but I'm trying to use loops instead

Comment: Your code looks like it would work to calculate BMI in either system of measurement. It is not clear how "appending to a list" will make it better. Are you simply trying to make your program continually ask the user for input so that additional BMI calculations can be done?

Comment: For this specific assignment, I'm required to put the imperial and metric data in lists. I didn't know that at first, so I designed my code differently. And no, I would just take the input for height and weight, put it in a list, and then do calculations.

Comment: you can append an element to a list using **list.append(element)**

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that is very helpful. However, I'm really just trying to figure out how the original code for inputting data would be switched and then how you'd be able to use the input from lists to calculate BMI

Comment: @William What are the exact requirements for your assignment? What exactly do you need to use a list for? What does the list represent? Do you want to repeatedly ask for weight and height and calculate BMI for each pair?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that there are better ways to learn about the use and functionality of lists than to use them for user input, however, you could pass a list to the `inputM()` and `inputI()` functions, add the user input to those lists, and then calculate the BMI from the items in the list. Here's an example for the metric BMI calculation:

```
def inputM(user_input):
    print("Enter weight in kg")
    user_input.append(float(input()))
    print("Enter height in meters")
    user_input.append(float(input()))

user_input = []
if request == "M":
  inputM(user_input)
  bmi = user_input[0]/(user_input[1]**2)
```

This shows how inconvenient and clumsy it is to use lists to capture user input in this scenario. Firstly, an empty list must be created and passed to the function. The function relies on the mutability of lists to return values to the calling code. And then the calling code needs access the result in a cumbersome way by accessing elements of the list by index, or by unpacking the list into variables, e.g.

```
inputM(user_input)
weightm, heightm = user_input[-2:]    # unpack the last 2 items in the list
```